# CSS breaks when adapting Bootstrap 3 carousel to Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to recreate a Bootstrap 3 testimonial slider that I saw on Codepen.
Here's the link - https://codepen.io/frontendor/pen/abBpXWj

Now I took this code and modified it to work with Bootstrap 5. The carousel itself works fine, but the CSS doesn't anymore. Here's the link to my Codepen with Bootstrap 5 and the same code adapted for the new version --

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" id="quote-carousel">
                    <!-- Carousel Slides/Quotes -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner text-center">
                        <!-- Quote 1 -->
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                            <blockquote>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-8 offset-sm-2">
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. !</p>
                                        <small>Someone famous</small>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </blockquote>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Quote 2 -->
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <blockquote>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-8 offset-sm-2">
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. </p>
                                        <small>Someone famous</small>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </blockquote>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Quote 3 -->
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <blockquote>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-8 offset-sm-2">
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. .</p>
                                        <small>Someone famous</small>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </blockquote>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Bottom Carousel Indicators -->
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-bs-target="#quote-carousel" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"><img class="img-responsive " src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/46.jpg" alt="">
                        </li>
                        <li data-bs-target="#quote-carousel" data-bs-slide-to="1"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://uifaces.co/our-content/donated/1H_7AxP0.jpg" alt="">
                        </li>
                        <li data-bs-target="#quote-carousel" data-bs-slide-to="2"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/36.jpg" alt="">
                        </li>
                    </ol>

                    <!-- Carousel Buttons Next/Prev -->
                    <a data-slide="prev" href="#quote-carousel" class="left carousel-control"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
                    <a data-slide="next" href="#quote-carousel" class="right carousel-control"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here's the corresponding CSS

```
#quote-carousel {
    padding: 0 10px 30px 10px;
    margin-top: 60px;
}
#quote-carousel .carousel-control {
    background: none;
    color: #CACACA;
    font-size: 2.3em;
    text-shadow: none;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
#quote-carousel .carousel-indicators {
    position: relative;
    right: 50%;
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: -19px;
}
#quote-carousel .carousel-indicators li {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 0.4;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all .4s ease-in;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#quote-carousel .carousel-indicators .active {
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all .2s;
}
.item blockquote {
    border-left: none;
    margin: 0;
}
.item blockquote p:before {
    content: "\f10d";
    font-family: 'Fontawesome';
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Link to this code -- https://codepen.io/yaddyvirus/pen/BadajPb

As I mentioned before, the carousel works fine, including the indicators, but everything else, including the controllers, are messed up immediately after I add the CSS. If I remove the CSS, the carousel once again works fine just in a very messed up manner.

What I should be getting is this - [image]

What I am getting is this - [image]

Once again, there has been no change to the HTML except adapting it to Bootstrap 5 and no change to the CSS at all.

Can someone point out what's wrong with the CSS? I don't assume I need to change the styling too when I adapted the carousel code to work with Bootstrap 5.

Answer (score 1):

In comparing the code side by side, it looks like you should be able to add the following for it to match. If it looks weird on mobile, I would look through the bootstrap css file and grab all rules associated with the ones you have placed in Codepen in your example:

```
.carousel-inner>.item>a>img, 
.carousel-inner>.item>img, 
.img-responsive, 
.thumbnail a>img, 
.thumbnail>img {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}

#quote-carousel .carousel-control {
    background: none;
    color: #CACACA;
    font-size: 2.3em;
    text-shadow: none;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.carousel-control-next, .carousel-control-prev {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 15%;
    padding: 0;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    background: 0 0;
    border: 0;
    opacity: .5;
    transition: opacity .15s ease;
}
.carousel-control-next:focus, 
.carousel-control-next:hover, 
.carousel-control-prev:focus, 
.carousel-control-prev:hover {
    background: none;
    color: #CACACA;
    font-size: 2.3em;
    text-shadow: none;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
blockquote .small, 
blockquote footer, 
blockquote small {
    display: block;
    font-size: 80%;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #777;
}
blockquote .small:before, 
blockquote footer:before, 
blockquote small:before {
    content: '\2014 \00A0';
}
button.carousel-control-prev,
button.carousel-control-next {
    background: none;
    color: #CACACA;
    font-size: 2.3em;
    text-shadow: none;
    margin-top: 30px;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
```

Comment: This fixes something, but the carousel controls still don't work and the images are still aligned to the left for some reason. Updated Codepen - https://codepen.io/yaddyvirus/pen/BadajPb

Comment: @YaddyVirus Gotcha. Just updated my answer with some more CSS I noticed. Try that and let me know how you get on.

Comment: I was under a bit of a deadline so I solved the problem for now by using the default bootstrap carousel's controls here. Worked like a charm but I'll try this on my page and let you know.

Comment: So I tried using your CSS, I get this - https://codepen.io/yaddyvirus/pen/BadajPb
The indicators are still in the bottom right, and the images are now small squares instead of circular.

Comment: That's strange because I added my css to your first example codepen and compared to the 2nd link and it looked the same

Comment: That shouldn't be happening. Let me give it another shot.

Comment: I gave it another shot and while it fixes the control button problem, the images are still small squares instead of circles

Comment: Crazy. I just checked and the images are circles haha